# How to write non-ascii from stdin to file properly

Tags: c, windows, stdin, utf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DWORD bytes_read;
    char buffer[65536];
    LPSTR str;

    ReadFile(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, 65536, &bytes_read, NULL);
    str = malloc(bytes_read);
    memcpy(str, buffer, bytes_read);

    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "stdin: %s", str);
    fprintf(f, "hardcoded: %s\n", "á");
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

when run in powershell via `echo á|.\Program.exe`, content of file.txt is:

`stdin: ?
ýýýýhardcoded: á`

I'm interested in replacing question mark with proper character retrieved from stdin

Comment: Do you have a simpler example? Just running your program ought to work just as well. The redirection only seems to muddle the question.

Comment: Your string isn't null terminated. You need to `malloc(bytes_read+1)` and then you need to ensure there is a terminating null in `buffer[bytes_read]`.

Comment: You are reading the file as though it is binary data, but printing it as though it is a null-terminated string.

Comment: 1. I don't have simpler example. 2. I'm aware ýýýý is because of missing null termination, but that is not target of this question. I'm interested in first character

Comment: 3. I need to read this as null-terminated string, this is just minimal reproducible example, full code is at https://github.com/amphp/windows-process-wrapper/blob/691e0cc6f1639d6ec4026d44aefa1738ccbf1031/src/ProcessWrapper.c#L537 which uses null terminated strings

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior. Nothing that happens should surprise you. Fix the glaring bug and try again.

Comment: PowerShell is encoding "á" as 7-bit ASCII and replacing non-ASCII characters with "?". The following sets the console codpages and PowerShell output encoding to UTF-8 without a BOM (i.e. byte order mark, i.e. initial byte sequence "\xef\xbb\xbf"): `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding
]::New($false)`.

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdin is apparently using CP437 charset. Reloading file with this encoding shows correct character